# How to Get text from Edit form in winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have wstring note and I want to get informaiton from my Edit box to this wstring note. I use :

```
 GetWindowText(hWnd, note.c_str(),100);
```

But it shows an error. Argument of type "const wchar_t* is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR".

What is good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c_str()` function returns a pointer to `const` memory.

The `GetWindowText` wants a pointer to non-`const` memory.

One solution in this case:

```
wchar_t buffer[100];
GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]));
note = buffer;
```

Or:

```
std::array<wchar_t, 100> buffer;
GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
note = buffer.data();
```

Comment: `+ 1` is not required. If the window text is 100 characters, it will be truncated to make room for the NUL terminator. `note = buffer` will naturally truncate the string in case it holds any embedded NUL characters.

Comment: Still truncates in case of embedded NUL characters.

Answer (score 1):

`GetWindowText()` wants a pointer to a writable buffer, but `c_str()` returns a pointer to `const` data, which is why you get the error.

You need to preallocate the `wstring`'s data buffer beforehand (you can use `GetWindowTextLength()` to help with that), and then you can pass a non-const pointer to that buffer, eg:

```cpp
wstring note;
int length = GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd);
if (length > 0)
{
    note.resize(length);
    length = GetWindowTextW(hWnd, note.data()/*or: &note[0]*/, length + 1);
    note.resize(length);
}
```

Note that *technically* this is *undefined behavior* prior to C++11, as the `wstring`'s `data()` and `operator[]` members were not *guaranteed* to return a pointer to data in contiguous memory, and the buffer was not *guaranteed* to be null-terminated. Only `c_str()` *guaranteed* those. But, MOST implementations used a single buffer to simplify `c_str()`, so you could *usually* just cast away the `const`, eg:

```cpp
wstring note;
int length = GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd);
if (length > 0)
{
    note.resize(length);
    length = GetWindowTextW(hWnd, const_cast<wchar_t*>(note.c_str()), length + 1);
    note.resize(length);
}
```

But, if you want to be legal about it, then prior to C++11 use a separate buffer and then copy it into the `wstring` afterwards, eg:

```cpp
wstring note;
int length = GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd);
if (length > 0)
{
    ++length;
    vector<wchar_t> buf(length);
    length = GetWindowTextW(hWnd, &buf[0], length);
    note.assign(&buf[0], length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the immediate problem is to use [string::data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) in place of `c_str`. Provided, that `note` is prepared to hold 100 code units.

A solution that doesn't arbitrarily limit the call to 100 code units involves calling [GetWindowTextLengthW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw) up front, and reserving enough storage in `note` prior to calling `GetWindowTextW`.

Comment: "*use `string::data` in place of `c_str`*" - assuming you are using C++17 or later, that is. Prior to C++17, `string::data()` returns the same `const char*` pointer as `c_str()`.

Comment: @rem A question tagged with the generic [tag:c++] tag assumes availability of the latest C++ standard.

Comment: ideally, that would be preferred, but in reality MANY (ie, MOST) questions do not actually follow that rule.